# Uploading APK to google play console doesn't work

Tags: android, react-native, apk, expo, google-play-console

**Problem**
I am trying to upload my app to the google play store, but when I do I get an error saying,

```
Upload failed
You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1.
```

I don't know why this is because this is the first version of my app to go onto the google store. I would love some help fixing this!

**app.json**

```
{
   "expo": {
    "name": "Phoenix",
    "icon": "./CandidtwoImages/Phoenixlogo.png",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "slug": "Phoenix",
    "sdkVersion": "21.0.0",
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.giise.phoenix"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.giise.phoenix"
    }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, and none of these solved it.

The solution:

In app.json

```
  "expo": {
     expo stuff
  },
  "android": {
     "versionCode": 2   
  },
```

put in versionCode and update to 2. It must be an integer (notice not in quotes)

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase **versionCode** in **build.gradle** :

```
 defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

**versionCode** - internal version number used to identified version on Google Play

**versionName** - version number shown to users

Details here : https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html

Comment: Although this answer is completely correct it isn't applicable in OP's problem since expo doesn't let any native build or code changes.

Comment: Yep, you're right. 
In Expo you need to change versionCode in app.json, details here https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/configuration.html#versioncode

Answer (score 0):

This happen because the frist time you upload an APK, it will automatically set as version 1, (in android studio also set version 1 - you can see at build.gradle). So you have to change version in build.gradle frist than generate and upload. Don't worry

Answer (score 0):

To update your app on store you need to update/change your version number too.

In expo this can be done through `app.json` [`version`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/configuration.html#version) prop.

To update your app you can use [expo's update](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/building-standalone-apps.html#7-update-your-app) feature too if you didn't change any native data or sdkVersion etc.

*Form Documentation of EXPO*

> For the most part, when you want to update your app, just Publish
>   again from exp or XDE. Your users will download the new JS the next
>   time they open the app. There are only a couple reasons why you might
>   want to rebuild and resubmit the native binaries:
>
> - If you want to change native metadata like the app’s name or icon
> - If you upgrade to a newer sdkVersion of your app (which requires new native code)
>
> To keep track of this, you can also update the binary’s versionCode
>   and buildNumber. It is a good idea to glance through the app.json
>   documentation to get an idea of all the properties you can change,
>   e.g. the icons, deep linking url scheme, handset/tablet support, and a
>   lot more.

Comment: but this isn't an update, this is the first time I've ever uploaded my app.

Answer (score -1):

Change the AndroidManifest file with the new version code.

```
<manifest 
          android:versionCode="1.1"
          android:versionName="1.1">
```

Comment: Every comment is telling me to change the version. I am kind of confused, what do I change it to? I know where to change it, just not what to.

Comment: that is the reason i have changed the code for you .. if you take a good look at it .. 
btw manifest file is in the main directory of application . go there open it and change the line of code that are mentioned above by simply adding a number in them like if it says andorid:versionCode=1.0 change it to 1.1